# Flow of node.js routing when using separate controller and router

Tags: node.js, routes

In my Node.js project I am using router file that imports controller files that have actual implementation of the methods. Like below.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
routes.mainApi(apiRoutes);
app.use('', apiRoutes);
```

**apiRoutes**

```
'use strict';
var controller = require('../controller/apiController');
var uploadController = require('../controller/uploadController');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

module.exports.mainApi = function (apiRouter) {

    apiRouter.post('/login', controller.login);

}
```

**apiController**

```
exports.login = function (req, res) {

// My code for login

};
```

I know when a api request comes then first app.js is executed. It further sends the request to apiRoutes as I called it in file. In apiRoutes when it finds 
    **apiRouts.post(./login,controller.login)** then it calls login function from controller. But I want to know that I am not passing **req** and **res** parameters anywhere in the login function then how they are being passed. Basically how this type of calling works.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this function `controller.login`
as a callback parameter of `r.post('path', callback)`

and when `controller.login` is actual called by `callback(request, response )` 
you will get `req and res`

Comment: This may be silly question. but its important for me as i don't know about it. Can you please explain me how request, response parameters created here in the callback. I mean as we do in Java we first create parameter then pass it in function call. But here we do not created these two parameters but they are being passed explicitly. How?

Comment: `post` is method defined by express, and has is own context , 
just like 
`
{    
   some  context has request and request     
   function post (method, callback) {    
      callback(response, request)    
  }    
 }    
`

and we call the post function by `r.post('path', callback)`